# Easily display icons from a DLL or EXE in registry format without external tools

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, icons

Is there any way to read icons from a DLL or EXE in registry format like `shell32.dll,48` or `explorer.exe,6`?

I would like to avoid external tools.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to do this without external tools.

- First create a temporary folder in your desktop (Or basically any location you like, just for convenience) with any name.
- Now right-click the Folder, click Properties and go to Customize tab.
- Click Change icons button in Folder Icons button.
- Now in the dialog box enter the full path of the .dll or .exe and choose the icon.
- Save the settings by clicking OK.
- Now open the folder and click View tab in explorer. Now click Folder options and in Advanced settings, select Show hidden files, folders, and drives and OK.
- Now open the Desktop.ini file in the folder.
- Look for a field named `IconResource` under `[.ShellClassInfo]` and that the value after equal sign is the value you are looking for!

Now you can use this in Registry and various other places. You can now also disable showing hidden files again.